# Java 8 Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to check if a particular object size is greater than 0. If it is greater than 0 then I want to create an optional object, if not then I want to return an Optional empty. This is the long version of the java code:

```
if(fooA.size>0) {
    return Optional.of(new Foo());
} else {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Is there any way to compact this into one line using java 8's optional library?

Comment: Do you actually have a `Stream` of objects, which you want to wrap this way or do you need to wrap only a single object? If you want to wrap only a single object... why use a `Stream`?

Comment: Why do you think the Stream API will help you here? This is nice, simple and readable code. I would perhaps reverse the condition and use `fooA.isEmpty()` if we're talking about a collection: what is the type of `fooA`?

Comment: `return fooA.size > 0 ? Optional.of(...) : Optional.empty()`?

Comment: What is the class of `fooA` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way to compact this into one line using java 8's optional library?

If you insist on using the Optional class, you could use [`Optional.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) and just pass it `null` if the condition isn't met:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(fooA.size > 0 ? new Foo() : null);
```

Note, however (as [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) [correctly states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328017/java-8-optional/37328241#comment62199914_37328241)) that using the Optional class doesn't give you any significant<sup>1</sup> advantage over just replacing your if/else statement with a ternary one (as [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) and Holger have both done in [their](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328017/java-8-optional/37328241#comment62175459_37328017) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328017/java-8-optional/37328241#comment62199914_37328241)):

```
return fooA.size > 0 ? Optional.of(new Foo()) : Optional.empty();
```

<sup>1</sup> The first line is a little shorter, which I usually consider an advantage, but an absolutely *insignificant* one in this case, as the length difference is negligible.

Comment: But there is no advantage in letting the `Optional` implementation perform an additional `null` check. Not to save four source code characters compared to `return fooA.size > 0 ? Optional.of(new Foo()) : Optional.empty();`

Comment: @Holger Of course there is no advantage over performing the check yourself, but it shouldn't hurt either, and the question specifically asks for it. I though about adding a line like yours to my answer, but by the time I submitted it, someone had already commented on the question with said statement. But sure, I can mention that.

Answer (score 7):

## Imperative Way

If you decide to stick to imperative programming, an if-else construct as yours is good as it is. Its readable, understandable and you gain nothing by simply reducing lines of code (unless you get paid for that and want to game the system).

The `(condition)?(true-branch):(false-branch)` construct is nice but may become poorly readable if it gets too complex. Some auto-format rules put each part of it into separate lines anyway. So think before using it.

The simplest way for putting the creation into a single line is to refactor the instantiation into a separate method and invoke it:

```
return newOptionalFoo(fooA.size > 0);

...

private Optional<Foo> newOptionalFoo(boolean condition) {
  if(condition) {
    return Optional.of(new Foo());
  } else {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

If you want to condense this to single line - imperative style - do this:

```
return condition ? Optional.of(new Foo()) : Optional.empty();
```

## Functional Way

In case you want to use functional programming, you should not mix functional and imperative programming when it is avoidable.
A proper functional way would be to wrap `fooA` into an Optional, filter on the condition and map to `Foo`. So if condition is not fulfilled, it is mapped to the empty `Optional`. I'd prefer this way.

```
return Optional.of(fooA).filter(f -> f.size > 0).map(f -> new Foo());
```

Alternatively you could create the `Optional` of `Foo` and use the filter so that the optional becomes empty if the filter condition does not match:

```
return Optional.of(new Foo()).filter(f -> fooA.size > 0);
```

But this would create an instance of `Foo` regardless of the condition beeing true or false. If you want to have lazy instantiation because creating a `Foo` is expensive, you could use a `Supplier` and map to `Foo` after filtering

```
return Optional.of((Supplier<Foo>) Foo::new)
               .filter(s -> fooA.size > 0)
               .map(Supplier::get)
```